# Laravel Scheduler monthlayAt weekdays combination

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduler

I'm quite new to the Laravel Scheduler. Currently there's an email sent out every 1st day of the month like this:

```
$schedule->job(new SendMonthlyUpdate)
    ->monthlyOn(1, '9:00')
    ->timezone('Europe/Amsterdam');
```

How would I change this if I want to always send it on the 1st day of the month, EXCEPT from weekends? In case the 1st (or 2nd) day is in a weekend, it should be triggered on Monday after the weekend.

I was considering something like this:

```
$schedule->job(new SendMonthlyUpdate)
    ->monthlyOn(1, '9:00')
    ->weekdays()
    ->timezone('Europe/Amsterdam');
```

But I'm not sure if:

A. This will entirely skip this job if the 1st day is in the weekend, rather than sending it later?

B. How to test this

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you will get your answer https://superuser.com/questions/709918/cronjob-for-first-day-of-month-except-sunday

Comment: Yes, your solution will skip the job if the first day of the month is weekend, and the job will never get done. For testing you have no choice but change the date of your system every time, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler than that:

```
$schedule->job(new SendMonthlyUpdate)
    ->monthly()
    ->weekdays();
```

Should do the job once per month as soon as it's a weekday.

In order to test it you will have to change the date of your system.